# Hadoop HDFS file recovery elapsed time (start time and end time)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, logfile, elapsedtime, file-recovery

I need to measure the speed of recovery for files with different file sizes stored with different storage policies (replication and erasure codes) in HDFS.

My question is: Is there a way to see the start time and end time (or simply the elapsed time in seconds) for a file recovery process in HDFS? For a specific file?

I mean the start time from where the system detects node failures (and starts the recovery process), and until HDFS recovers the data (and possibly reallocates nodes) and makes the file "stable" again?

Maybe I can look into some metadata files or log files of the particular file to see some timestamps etc? Or is there a file where I can see all the activity of a HDFS file?

I would really appreciate some terminal commands to get this info.

Thank you so much in advance!